# Zooming in picturebox but with same resolution

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, zooming

I have a picturebox with zooming/pan capabilities. I am now starting with the zoom. I did that by:

1. getting the mousescroll event( up or down)
2. add height and width to the picturebox
3. get the pixel coordinates of mouse inside the image.

my problem is that, when i change the size of the picturebox, the pixel coordinates in the picture is not the same with the previous image without zoom. I need the coordinates to be the same even the picture is zoomed.

Comment: You need to provide an top/left offset, so that when you zoom out/in, you can subtract the top/left of the image with the offset of your zoom.

Comment: You want the zoom functionality to increase the size of the image including its boundaries? This sounds more like a scale function than a zoom; a zoom would increase the magnification and crop the image. So, if I understand correctly, you want to scale the image and its container (picturebox) with the mouse cursor as the point of origin?

Comment: @ JYelton what i really wanna do is a city map and have some nodes in a particular (x,y) position in the image and implement the dijkstras algorithm. I have a list of coordinates with their corresponding streetnames, if the user clicks on the picturebox, the program will check if its in the list and what is its streetname. i have a picturebox that is inside the panel so that when i zoom it in, the picturebox dont overflow inside the form. but now the problem is, after the picturebox zoomed, the coordinates changes and it will not correspond with the list of coordinates that i have.

Comment: @George thanks, my problem was solved! :)..ill go now with panning ^^